# How do write the current state of a window to a png, and then asemble them into a mp4 file?

Tags: opengl, video, d, mp4

I'm making an animation software, which is very different from other animators. Mine has an interpreter which will turn an script into a bunch of png files, and then sum them up in a mp4 file. I have made the interpreter, everything works but I still don't know how to:
use OpenGL (in D)
and take screenshots of my animator's window
and finally assemble the pngs into a mp4

My question here is that, is there a way to use OpenGL in D, and how do I assemble pngs into mp4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out exactly what I was looking for, here is the D binding for OpenGL: http://www.dsource.org/projects/derelict and to put pngs into a video, I could use ffmpeg.

EDIT: And also dlib is also very useful: https://github.com/gecko0307/dlib/

Comment: be careful, dsource is obsolete so take care to use the right bindings, those from the Derelict Organization; https://github.com/DerelictOrg.